# How to introduce new index values in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, insert

I have the following dataframe, which the `print(df_74034.head(10))`is:

```
                          HumExamRoom                      HumTechRoom Machine  TempExamRoom TempTechRoom
                                   NaN  2017-08-18\t09:22:33\t65.9   74034           NaN          NaN
                                   NaN  2017-10-03\t11:08:26\t60.5   74034           NaN          NaN
2018-02-17\t01:45:24          NaN                             69.7   74034           NaN          NaN
2018-02-17\t01:45:55          NaN                             67.5   74034           NaN          NaN
2018-02-17\t01:46:29          NaN                             65.4   74034           NaN          NaN
2018-02-17\t01:47:20          NaN                             63.3   74034           NaN          NaN
2018-02-17\t01:48:35          NaN                             61.3   74034           NaN          NaN
2018-02-17\t01:49:08          NaN                             63.4   74034           NaN          NaN
2018-02-17\t01:49:31          NaN                             65.5   74034           NaN          NaN
2018-02-17\t01:49:55          NaN                             67.6   74034           NaN          NaN
```

(The first two rows got a little messy)
As you can see, the first two cells in the index have no values at all because their values are in the second column, which is probably a fault of my code - which I don't want to change anymore. Therefore, I would like to introduce the values `2017-08-18\t09:22:33\t` and `2017-08-18\t09:22:33\t' in the index cells, respectively, and sort it. In order to sort I also have to change it to its correct date/time format.

I've already tried `df_74034.index.insert(0, '2017-08-18\t09:22:33')` but it didn't work. I appretiate for the help!

Comment: Rather than the code, is possible you have a tabular instead of spaces in the text file from which you import the data?

Comment: @Valentino maybe.. I'll check it. But apparently not.

Comment: To insert into empty indices, you can create new series with the datetime and set_index again. To sort by datetime it should be in correct format, i didn't get it why there \t in between datetime.

Comment: @xanjay \t is just the format it was in the txt file from which I garnered all the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform it in other way -

df = dataframe name which in your case is df_74034.

1. You may try df.reset_index() which will place the current index values with integer number and will create column of your existing index value.
2. Create a new column of the values you want to set as index. Lets say name of the column is ABC
3. Then, you can use df.set_index('ABC',inplace=True) which will create a new index with values those are in ABC column.

I hope it may be helpful to some extend.

Comment: Hey thanks! That's is an option! I'll try it. I was rather looking for a way to get those values from the second column into the index. But it seems a hard thing to do. Thank you again!

Comment: It didn't work. :( Apparently because in my code I've set date/time as index. I don't know. it should work but didn't. I'll have to try another thing... :/

Comment: You mean to say df. reset_index() failing in your case?

Comment: `df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)` it worked! :D

Comment: I'm trying to change that two vacuous values with `df_74034.replace({'data/hora': {0: '2017-08-18\t09:22:33', 1: '2017-10-03\t11:08:26'}}, inplace=True)`. But is not working!! :(

Comment: I am sorry. I could not understand what  'data/hora' is ?df_74034.replace({'data/hora': {0: '2017-08-18\t09:22:33', 1: '2017-10-03\t11:08:26'}}, inplace=True)

Comment: In problem you mentioned you want to replace index values.Did I perceive it incorrectly?